# Connected components of a metric space are complete subspaces.

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

If somene have just a hint for me i would be very grateful, because i don't know how to start. Let $A$ be a connected componente of $x \in M$,with $(M,d)$ metric space. Supose that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is a cauchy sequence in $A$. I can't apply the definition of cauchy sequence, and can't use the fact that the connected component is a closed set.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, but this doesn’t seem true. Consider $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ with the Euclidean metric. Neither of the two connected components is complete.

Comment: You'r right. I think is missing some hipotesis in the problem. Becouse if the metric space is complete, then is very easy to prove as @josé carlos Santos said below.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that the whole space is complete, then it's only a matter of using these facts:

- every connected component is a closed subset;
- every closed subset of a complete metric space is also complete.

On the other hand, without assuming that the whole space is complete, then the statement is just plain false. Observe that if $M$ is connected, then its only connected component is $M$ itself, which may well not be complete.